# syntax error in string in query in VBA access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, syntax

I get 3075 error running this line in vba access:

```
Dim sqlMZG As String
sqlMZG = "SELECT MAZeitenGesamt.* Where MAZeitenGesamt.MA = 'JPA' FROM MAZeitenGesamt;"
```

Where JPA is a constant  value. I tried the following forms and none of them worked.

```
SELECT MAZeitenGesamt.* Where MAZeitenGesamt.[MA] = '" & "JPA" & "' FROM MAZeitenGesamt;

SELECT MAZeitenGesamt.* Where MAZeitenGesamt.MA = '" & "JPA" & "' FROM MAZeitenGesamt;

SELECT MAZeitenGesamt.* Where MAZeitenGesamt.MA = ""JPA"" FROM MAZeitenGesamt;

SELECT MAZeitenGesamt.* Where MAZeitenGesamt.MA = \"JPA\"  FROM MAZeitenGesamt;

SELECT MAZeitenGesamt.* Where MAZeitenGesamt.MA = \'JPA\' FROM MAZeitenGesamt;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the proper format for a query is like this: "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE something = x" so in your case: "SELECT MAZeitenGesamt.* FROM MAZeitenGesamt WHERE MAZeitenGesamt.MA = 'JPA'"

Comment: @gizlmeier -- I'd recommend you add that as an answer, as I think you have correctly addressed Mary's issue

Comment: @gizlmeier the problem was what u said. do u wanna send it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you use a parameter rather than quoting a literal.  That said, @gizlmeier is right, in that your syntax is wrong to begin with.

```
Dim sqlMZG As String
sqlMZG = "parameters [MAParam] text; " & _
  "SELECT MAZeitenGesamt.* FROM MAZeitenGesamt Where MAZeitenGesamt.MA = [MAParam];"
```

From there, when you create your query you can set the value for the parameter:

```
Set qry = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("GetMaz", sqlMZG)
qry.Parameters("MAParam") = JPA
```

No messy quoting to worry about and such.

Comment: That is: `qry.Parameters("MAParam") = "JPA"`

Comment: Oh, it's a literal?  I thought JPA was a variable containing the actual value...  my bad.  If it's a literal, then the parameter isn't quite as helpful